# Could you use Nuget / OpenWrap to manage remote deployments?

Tags: deployment, nuget

I haven't thought this through to completion, but it seems that if nuget is a tool for managing the inclusion of packages in a known location, could it not be used as a deployment tool for web servers (a website being just a very large package itself)?

A service running on the web server would ping a nuget server for updates, and install them when available. There would have to be some additional management (recycling app pools, making sure that all your webservers don't update at the same time etc.), but I think it could work?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's definitly on the roadmap for openrasta/openwrap, so it's not a crazy idea. Some people already have done some of that work themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is usually known as a Continuous Integration (CI for short) setup.  You could probably cobble something together with Nuget but there are already some pretty good tools out there.  [Cruise](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) and [TFS](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362&rct=j&q=team%20foundation%20server&ei=jLXITZ78L8TVgQfe5sGFBg&usg=AFQjCNGNz0CAB_LMr7fQ8dmYvWDLWVljuA&cad=rja) to name a couple.

If you're looking for a mad scientist project though, carry on and let the community know what you come up with!

Comment: No it isn't. Continuous integration (using cc.net / team city etc) is used to manage automated builds and source code- compiling builds, running automated tests, exporting release packages etc. We already have a very comprehensive CI setup. I'm talking about the final mile - actually deploying the software to multiple servers in a controlled fashion - which could become part of a Continuous Delivery process.

Comment: Right, exporting release packages.  I assumed that usually when someone discusses this type of setup it is in the context of a build environment.  You are correct that CI does a lot more than deployment.  But TFS and, I thought, Cruise both have very good deployment options built in - i.e. MSDeploy/TFS2010.